# Using switch, ternary, or an object instead of if/else for the "step" event this animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, ternary-operator

I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this, or one that uses less text, rather than using a bunch of if/else statements.

Currently I have this handling picture changes to be made during the animation:

```
link.animate({
            top: '0'
        }, {
            duration: 3000*(Math.random()+1),
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',

            step: function(now, tween) {
                if (now < -300){
                    $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', '');
                } else if (now < -250) {
                    $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', ...);
                } else if (now < -200) {
                    $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', ...);
                } ... etc.
```

If I can use a switch statement, ternary operators, or an object for the "step" function instead of the if/else statements, could somebody provide examples on how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither. Just use a formula to get the file name from the `now` value, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example on how to do this? I'm not sure I could figure it out on my own.

Comment: Can you show the mapping from the intervals to the actual filenames, please? Then it's probably something like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+round+to+nearest)

Comment: } else if (now < -250) {
    $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', 'images/home/shadow-pngs/shadow-5.png');
} else if (now < -200) {
   $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', 'images/home/shadow-pngs/shadow-4.png'); (Is this what you requested?)

Comment: Yes. What happens `>= 0`?

Comment: The last line I have is _else if (now >= -50) { $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', 'images/home/shadow-pngs/splat-shadow.png'); }_ It's just the last shadow image to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you need a different image base on a `50px` difference. 50 is the key here. I'd suggest to use an array of source where the lower `px`is the first in array :

```
var arr = ['srcFor0px', 'srcFor50px', 'srcFor100px', 'srcFor150px', 'srcFor200px'...];
```

Then, know what's your lower value (in this example -300 is the lower). You will then need to add the lowest value to the current value:

```
var comparison = now - -300
```

After that, you'll need to do a math ceil on the result divided by 50.

```
var index = Math.ceil(comparison / 50);
```

Then the only thing remaining is to see if the index if inbound. Basically, just check if the index is below 0 or higher than the array length :

```
if(index < 0) index = 0;
else if(index >= arr.length) index = arr.length-1;
```

Then you get the good source in the array. Final code would look like that :

```
step : function(now){
    var arr = ['srcFor-300px', 'srcFor-250px', 'srcFor-200px', 'srcFor-150px', 'srcFor-100px'];
    var comparison = now - -300
    var index = Math.ceil(comparison / 50);

    if(index < 0) index = 0;
    else if(index >= arr.length) index = arr.length-1;

    $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', arr[index]);
}
```

Comment: I can't claim to truly comprehend this, but it's very interesting. So `comparison` gets the difference in position, and `index` creates an index number (using `comparison`) that can be associated with the array. I'm trying this out soon, thanks.

Comment: Well it is working, so even though I don't fully comprehend it I think I will make use of this answer. :)

Comment: Well yeah, i guess it can be complicated, but really, it is just mathematics! `comparison` is there to base the index around the `0` since the first cell in array is `0`. By doing so, it allow that if `now` is -299 or higher, `(now - -300) / 50` will be higher than 0. Any number between 0 and 1 when rounded to the ceil will be equal to 1. But if `now` is -249, `(now - -300) / 50` will be higher than 1. That number rounded to ceil will be 2.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good at math, so I appreciate the continued explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the answer you are specifically looking for, but what about reducing the amount of code you're putting in the if statements instead?

```
        step: function(now, tween) {
            var src;
            if (now < -300){
               src = 'a';
            } else if (now < -250) {
               src = 'b';
            } else if (now < -200) {
               src = 'c';
            } ... etc.
                $("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', src);
```

Although other control statements do exist, the ultimate goal towards elegant code is to reduce the amount of code while increasing the ability to understand it.
Only assigning the src variable inside the control flow statements eliminates duplicate code.

Comment: I'm game to try it, but I'm not 100% sure how "src" is working here; Would 'a' or 'b' be replaced by actual URLs? Also, is only a single "$("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr" needed at the very end? (Is that because "src" is the only thing that needs to change?)

Comment: var  `src = 'a'; ` results in the variable  `src ` being declared and then getting the value of a. (It is declared so that it's available outside the if statements)

  `$("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', src); ` is the code that changes the attribute  `'src' ` to the value of the variable by the name of  `src `. Only one change is required by your code, so multiple lines of code that perform changes are not required. The only thing that truly deserves multiple lines of code is for each possible decision for changing it to.

Please beware: my snippet always re-assigns it!

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with Karl-André Gagnon's answer, but this was still a good alternative.

Comment: No problem! - Both solutions are `DRY`, but his rewrite of your code results in fewer Lines of Code and control flow statements.
Arguably (objectively, in terms of maintainability metrics), it is therefore a superior solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the repetitive comparisons by a bit of maths:

```
var num = Math.ceil(now/-50)-1;
if (num > 5)
    var src = "";
else {
    var src = 'images/home/shadow-pngs/';
    if (num > 0)
        src += 'shadow'+num;
    else
        src += 'splat-shadow';
    src += '.png';
}
$("#"+ link.data("shadow")).attr('src', src);
```